# Eigenvalue distribution of a band matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, eigenvalues, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

Let $\mathbf M_i$ be rectangular matrices of dimensions $N_{i-1}\times N_i$. We assume that their entries are random, with zero mean and variance $\sigma_i^2$.

For some positive integer $k$, I define the matrix $\mathbf{A}_k$:

$$\mathbf{A}_k = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
  0 & \mathbf{M}_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
  \mathbf{M}_1^{\top} & 0 & \mathbf{M}_2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
  0 & \mathbf{M}_2^{\top} & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \mathbf{M}_n\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \mathbf{M}_k^{\top} & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Notice that $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric. But unfortunately it is not from a rotationally invariant random ensemble, which has complicated things for me.

I have two questions.

1. What is the eigenvalue density of $\mathbf{A}_k$?
2. What happens to the eigenvalue density when I set $N_i=c_iN$, with positive constants $c_i$ and we take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$? I presume one must perform an appropriate re-scaling here to get a meaningful result.

Even if the answer to 1. is not tractable, maybe the limiting form 2. can still be obtained.

**Update:** Say I have access to the singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{M}_i$. Can we say anything about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}_k$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538580/positive-definiteness-of-a-block-diagonal-matrix

Answer (score 0):

1. A closed form expression for finite $N$ is most certainly not available.
2. A large-$N$ calculation for Gaussian distributed matrix elements has been reported in [Density of eigenvalues of random band matrices](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.44.2800). If the band width $\delta N$ increases with $N$ as $N^\beta$ for some $\beta>0$, the eigenvalue density tends in the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ to the usual semicircle that one would obtain for the full Gaussian matrix (so for $\delta N=N$).

Comment: This is not quite the same model. The model here seems closer to the Wegner orbital model, but again not quite because of the identity on the diagonal blocks. There is some work of Peled, Shenker, Shamis and Sodin on the latter, and also work of Scherbina^2  using supersymmetry methods https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03813. But  I stress this is not exactly the same model.

Comment: I also think that it's not the same model. Please note I have updated the question, simplifying it.